# ¿Cómo realizar estas dos consultas de MySQL en PHP y obtener una tabla con los resultados?

Tags: php, sql

Nunca he usado este tipo de consulta y no sé como implementarla en php, pongo primero las tablas relacionadas con la consulta, y después la consulta que quiero usar en php. Gracias, un saludo.

**Tabla: team_driver**

```
Columna Tipo    Nulo Predeterminado Comentarios
id      int(11) No      
team    int(11) No   0  
driver  int(11) No   0
```

**Ejemplo:**

```
id  team driver
104 26   1
```

---

**tabla: race_driver**

```
Columna      Tipo       Nulo Predeterminado Comentarios
race         int(11)    No   0  
team_driver  int(11)    No   0  
grid         int(11)    No   0  
position     int(11)    No   0  
fastest_lap  tinyint(1) No   0  
laps         int(11)    No   0  
time         int(11)    No   0  
status       int(11)    No   0
```

**Ejemplo:**

```
race team_driver grid position fastest_lap laps time    status
26   104         6    3        0           20   2588975 0
23   104         1    1        1           15   1946151 0
22   104         6    5        0           27   2473936 0
```

---

**Tabla: driver**

```
Columna      Tipo         Nulo Predeterminado Comentarios
id           int(11)      No        
name         varchar(30)  No        
driver_photo varchar(200) No
```

**Ejemplo:**

```
id  name  driver_photo
1   Spark http://spark.byethost17.com/prem/uploads/spark.png
```

---

Creando una vista con todos los resultados y contando solo los top 3 identificados por su ID de team driver:

```
CREATE VIEW team_driver_top3 AS
SELECT team_driver,
sum(case when position = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as position_1_count,
sum(case when position = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as position_2_count,
sum(case when position = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as position_3_count
from race_driver
group by team_driver
order by position_1_count desc
```

---

Sumando los resultados:

```
SELECT name,
SUM(position_1_count) AS pos_1,
SUM(position_2_count) AS pos_2,
SUM(position_3_count) AS pos_3 
FROM team_driver, team_driver_top3, driver 
WHERE (team_driver.id = team_driver_top3.team_driver AND team_driver.driver = driver.id) 
GROUP BY driver
ORDER BY pos_1 DESC, pos_2 DESC, pos_3 DESC;
```

---

Reedito para responder y aclarar conforme se me ha pedido en los comentarios:

Cuando pregunto es porque ya lo he intentado por mi cuenta con mis limitados conocimientos. El problema que tengo es la sintaxis, y quizás que en php hay que hacer algo más de código para conseguir los resultados.

No es un formulario, es solo una consulta que muestra una tabla. Le he dado mil vueltas durante meses, y la mejor forma de obtener una tabla que me sume los podiums (positions) es esa, como me ayudaron me falta el paso de hacer funcionar la consulta en php, ya que no es de las que esté habituado a ver. https://github.com/arv187/PREM-Podium-race-E-manager/issues/28

El código que obtengo en phpmyadmin al seleccionar "obtener código php":

```
$sql = "SELECT team_driver,\n"
. " sum(case when position = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as position_1_count,\n"
. " sum(case when position = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as position_2_count,\n"
. " sum(case when position = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as position_3_count\n"
. "from race_driver\n"
. "group by team_driver\n"
. "order by position_1_count desc LIMIT 0, 30 ";
```

Cuando formateo correctamente el código por ejemplo eliminando \n obtengo un error T_string select team_driver. Hablo de memoría porque no recuerdo los detalles desde esta mañana y revertí los cambios al darme ese error. Cuando he buscado php sql he visto cosas que no entendia, así que no me sirvió de mucho, ni siquiera sé a que se referían con usar ajax. Así que al final publiqué aquí como último recurso, porque sé que es complicado obtener una respuesta concreta si se pregunta.

Vamos que creo que varios meses y 5 horas hoy intentando aplicar la consulta debería tenerse en cuenta para comprender que no doy más de mí y necesito ayuda xD.

Gracias por las respuestas, un saludo!.

Comment: Creo que estás confundido o la pregunta no es clara: no se pasa una consulta de SQL a PHP, lo que se haría en ese caso sería _enviar_ la consulta al manejador de base de datos _desde_ PHP. Para ello puedes usar PDO (cualquier DBMS) o MySQLi (sólo MySQL).

Comment: Añadiendo al comentario de @A.Cedano, deberías de publicar al menos el formato de tu documento HTML con los campos donde ingresaras dichos datos y agregar el contexto de las tablas, es decir que función tiene el sistema y que resultados esperamos conseguir, recordando que debes hacer el esfuerzo por tratar de resolver lo mas que puedas del problema y luego preguntar :) para así ayudarte a resolverlo y no hacerlo todo por ti (no te ayudaría). Así que te invito a hacer el [tour] y cualquier cosa te ayudaremos!

Comment: Y, si buscas en las preguntas ya respondidas `php sql` (o `php mysql`) encontrarás muchos ejemplos...

Comment: Cuando pregunto es porque ya lo he intentado por mi cuenta con mis limitados conocimientos. El problema que tengo es la sintaxis, y quizás que en php hay que hacer algo más de código para conseguir los resultados.

Le di a la tecla intro y no terminé de explicar, reedito este comentario para seguir lo que me habéis ido diciendo y explicarlo mejor.

Comment: Un ejemplo de lo que conseguí por mi cuenta http://prem.hol.es/prem/?page=show_drivers (pero los pilotos se repiten por cada equipo que hayan tenido o tengan). Este es el código html/php que conseguí elaborar tras meses pero que tiene el fallo que comento: https://github.com/arv187/PREM-Podium-race-E-manager/blob/master/show_drivers.php

Por favor, no me digais que no use mysql y cambie a mysqli, porque ya lo sé xD, lo tengo pendiente y creo que optaré por usar alguna herramienta conversora y repasar después, https://github.com/arv187/PREM-Podium-race-E-manager/issues/1

Comment: @arv187 Te recomiendo para sustentar la respuesta de A.Cedano entrar a esta pagina web: `phpdelusions.net/pdo` , donde encontraras una forma y eficiente de realizar consultas `SQL` usando `PDO` y realmente es muy facil!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno, pues gracias por no ayudarme y marearme con que si código obsoleto, intentar meterme en historias de PDO, volver a hacerme repetir comprobaciones que ya había hecho y ni diciéndolo se dejaba de repetir que volviera a hacerlo... todo menos darme una solución.

En lo que va de año con esta ya fueron dos ocasiones en las que pedí ayuda y no conseguí solución.

Eso sí, muchisimas gracias por vuestras respuestas y dedicar vuestro tiempo a responder e intentar ayudar.

Aquí está la solución:

```
<? if (!defined("CONFIG"))
    exit();

$sql_drivers = "SELECT name, driver_photo,
    SUM(position_1_count) AS pos_1,
    SUM(position_2_count) AS pos_2,
    SUM(position_3_count) AS pos_3
FROM team_driver, team_driver_top3, driver
WHERE (team_driver.id = team_driver_top3.team_driver AND team_driver.driver = driver.id)
GROUP BY driver
ORDER BY driver.name ASC;";
$exe_drivers = mysql_query($sql_drivers);
if (!$exe_drivers) {
    show_error("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error() . "\n");
    return;
}
?>
```

Además se crea esta tabla en la base de datos:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `team_driver_top3` AS
SELECT `race_driver`.`team_driver` AS `team_driver`,
  sum((case when (`race_driver`.`position` = 1) then 1 else 0 end)) AS `position_1_count`,
  sum((case when (`race_driver`.`position` = 2) then 1 else 0 end)) AS `position_2_count`,
  sum((case when (`race_driver`.`position` = 3) then 1 else 0 end)) AS `position_3_count`
FROM `race_driver`
GROUP BY `race_driver`.`team_driver`
ORDER BY pos_1 DESC, pos_2 DESC, pos_3 DESC;";
```

Comment: Te propuse en mi respuesta dos soluciones mejores, una con PDO y otra con MySQLi. No entiendo la solución por la que has optado, teniendo que recurrir a la creación de una `VIEW` para esto. Es una solución más costosa que como te he indicado más arriba.

Answer (score 1):

Ahora que has editado la pregunta se entiende mejor el problema.

Efectivamente recuerdo haber leído hace unos meses una pregunta sobre este tema.

Como sospechaba, hay un problema con respecto a entender como funcionan las cosas. En realidad, no se trata de *convertir* código. Es decir, no es que tengas una consulta SQL y tengas que convertirla a PHP. La consulta será manejada siempre en el programa de base de datos y debe ser escrita *casi* como si te encontrases dentro de él, pues PHP hace digamos de intermediario, enviando al manejador de base de datos la consulta.

Por lo tanto, no se trata de *convertir* tu consulta, como se ve que estás intentando:

```
//Esto no va a funcionar ...

$sql = "SELECT team_driver,\n"
. " sum(case when position = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as position_1_count,\n"
. " sum(case when position = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as position_2_count,\n"
. " sum(case when position = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as position_3_count\n"
. "from race_driver\n"
. "group by team_driver\n"
. "order by position_1_count desc LIMIT 0, 30 ";
```

Sino de escribir tu consulta como si estuvieses en el DBMS y mandarla a través de alguna API de PHP destinada para ello (PDO, MySQLi...). Así que en PHP la consulta tiene que estar escrita así:

```
/*
 * Esto sí va a funcionar ...
 * ¡atención a algunos espacios que faltaban!
 * las \n al final darían error en el DBMS, porque es código de PHP
*/


$sql = "SELECT team_driver, "
. " sum(case when position = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as position_1_count,"
. " sum(case when position = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as position_2_count,"
. " sum(case when position = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as position_3_count"
. " from race_driver"
. " group by team_driver"
. " order by position_1_count desc LIMIT 0, 30";
```

Cuando envías esa consulta usando una de las API recomendadas, obtienes los resultados y puedes presentarlos en pantalla.

Veamos dos ejemplos, uno con PDO y otro con MySQLi. Yo particularmente recomiendo usar PDO.

#### Ejemplo con PDO

Mostraré la parte principal. **[En este enlace](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/tcy5-b093)** hay un ejemplo completo y funcional con el código bien documentado sobre la forma de crear la conexión y los métodos que se van utilizando para enviar la consulta y leer los datos.

```
...
$sql = "SELECT team_driver, "
. " sum(case when position = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as position_1_count,"
. " sum(case when position = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as position_2_count,"
. " sum(case when position = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as position_3_count"
. " from race_driver"
. " group by team_driver"
. " order by position_1_count desc LIMIT 0, 30";

$result = $pdo->query($sql);
$arrDatos = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if ($arrDatos)
{

    $strHtml="<table border='1'>";
    $strHtml.= "<th>POSITION 1</th><th>POSITION 2</th><th>POSITION 3</th>";
    $strHtml.="<tbody>";

    foreach ($arrDatos as $row)
    {
        $strHtml.= "<tr>";
        $strHtml.= "<td>".$row["position_1_count"]."</td>";
        $strHtml.= "<td>".$row["position_2_count"]."</td>";
        $strHtml.= "<td>".$row["position_3_count"]."</td>";
        $strHtml.= "</tr>";
    }

$strHtml.="</tbody>";
$strHtml.="</table>";
echo $strHtml;

...
```

---

#### Ejemplo con MySQLi:

Mostraré la parte principal. **[En este enlace](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ck5y-jc3j)** hay un ejemplo completo y funcional con el código bien documentado sobre la forma de crear la conexión y los métodos que se van utilizando para enviar la consulta y leer los datos.

```
...
$sql = "SELECT team_driver, "
. " sum(case when position = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as position_1_count,"
. " sum(case when position = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as position_2_count,"
. " sum(case when position = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as position_3_count"
. " from race_driver"
. " group by team_driver"
. " order by position_1_count desc LIMIT 0, 30";

$resultado=$mysqli->query($sql);


if ($resultado) 
{
    if($resultado->num_rows === 0)
    {

        echo "No se  encontraron datos";

    }else{

        $strHtml="<table border='1'>";
        $strHtml.= "<th>POSITION 1</th><th>POSITION 2</th><th>POSITION 3</th>";
        $strHtml.="<tbody>";

        while ($row = $resultado->fetch_array())
        {
            $strHtml.= "<tr>";
            $strHtml.= "<td>".$row["position_1_count"]."</td>";
            $strHtml.= "<td>".$row["position_2_count"]."</td>";
            $strHtml.= "<td>".$row["position_3_count"]."</td>";
            $strHtml.= "</tr>";
        }

        $strHtml.="</tbody>";
        $strHtml.="</table>";
        echo $strHtml;
    ...
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta, disculpa que me comunique por aquí, tienes alguna forma en la que pueda contactarte, no he podido invitarte a un chat (no se como xD)

Comment: Gracias @Victor-Random los chats me producen _claustrofobia_.

Comment: Gracias a todos,
 @Victor-Random no estoy seguro de si debo de terminar de entender mysqli antes de meterme en PDO o no importa.

En este caso
    $resultado=$mysqli->query($sql);
No lo había visto nunca (entiendo que la variable $resultado es igual a la consulta de mysqli de la variable $sql), otro problema es que no entiendo mucho de arrays, sé que es como un listado que se almacena. Estoy haciendo cosas en codeacademy.com para ir aprendiendo. Me apunto las dos webs que me habéis dado e iré probando. Gracias.

Comment: @arv187 MySQLi y PDO son dos API, puedes optar por cualquiera de ellas y aprenderlas/usarlas sin tener que aprender la otra. Yo recomendaría PDO, usada como una clase la cual llamarías cada vez que necesites usar la conexión. Tengo una disponible en Github por si te interesa. Lo que hace  `$resultado=$mysqli->query($sql);`  es almacenar en la variable `$resultado` lo que devuelve el método [`query`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php) de MySQLi para luego evaluar si la consulta tuvo éxito o no. Luego se usa el mismo `$result` con otro método para obtener los resultados de la consulta.

Comment: @arv187 puedes empezar por aqui, este es un libro de php que trabaja con PDO y te explica todo de cero: https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/mylekha-ebook/IT+%26+Programming/PHP/Learning-PHP.pdf y aqui los ejercicios que trae resueltos: http://web.nmsu.edu/~oc/cs479/hw1.php
http://web.nmsu.edu/~oc/cs479/hw2.php
http://web.nmsu.edu/~oc/cs479/hw3.php
http://web.nmsu.edu/~oc/cs479/hw4.php

y aqui otros video tutoriales en español: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-b4lN7o-UKs

Comment: Gracias a los dos

Comment: @A.Cedano estoy obteniendo el siguiente error: Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null in /home/... on line 12 $resultado=$mysqli->query($sql);
Cambié $mysqli por $config ya que tengo un archivo  externo de configuración de la base de datos https://github.com/arv187/PREM-Podium-race-E-manager/blob/master/config.php.dist pero obtengo este error:
Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on array  in /home/... on line 12 $resultado=$config->query($sql);

Comment: El primer error, con `$mysqli` indica que no se está creando bien la conexión, no sé si viste [el ejemplo completo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ck5y-jc3j), el código está comentado e indica cómo crear la conexión: `$mysqli = new mysqli($host_name, $user_name, $pass_word, $database_name, $port);`, se explica el significado de cada variable. Ver también el [Manual de PHP](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.construct.php). El error que te da con `$config` es que tu archivo no devuelve un objeto conexión, sino un array. Para empezar, prueba como indico en el ejemplo del enlace @arv187

Comment: Sí, ya lo vi. No quiero crear una conexión por cada archivo php del sistema, de hecho ningún archivo tiene un código para crear una conexión y las consultas funcionan bien. Creo que por que el archivo index.php ya realiza esa conexión o ya está incluida la función en https://github.com/arv187/PREM-Podium-race-E-manager/blob/master/functions.php Lo que intentaba con $config es usar ya esa variable y no tener que volver a definir la conexión.

Comment: Es un buen método el que estás implementando: tener un archivo que gestione la conexión @arv187 pero viendo el enlace que compartes, ese código no crea una conexión `mysqli`  sino una conexión de la extensión `mysql` (obsoleta). Yo recomendaría que pases el código definitivamente a PDO. Si quieres puedes usar **[esta clase](https://github.com/padrecedano/PHP-PDO)**, es de mi autoría y me funciona muy bien en mis proyectos.

Comment: @A.Cedano, gracias, hice una conexión mysqli nueva en el propio archivo php de la consulta, pero sigo queriendo utilizar mi archivo de conexión a parte y no sé como hacerlo.
Voy a tener que pasar todo a mysqli en algún momento pero usaré un conversor y luego leyendo el manual de php veré si se ha hecho correctamente. PDO lo descarto, me cuesta entender mysql, mysqli un poco más, pero PDO sería ir de 1 a 0 otra vez en conocimiento y cambiar todo el sistema que no es poco y muchas partes ni entiendo como funcionan para pasarlas a mysqli menos aún a PDO. Es darle una 2ª vida a la app para que

Comment: otras personas puedan crear sus ligas/campeonatos de coches con sus amigos importando los resultados de assetto corsa y otros. Si llego a saber que el programador me deja tirado o que es imposible que otro se quiera implicar ni me meto. Así que intento acabar lo que dejaron a medias por lo menos y pasarlo a mysqli al final. Gracias

Comment: Luego tengo el problema de hacer la segunda consulta basada en la primera, me refiero a que en la primera tengo esto sum(case when position = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as position_1_count, y en la segunda tengo que coger ese position_1_count...2...3.... para esto SUM(position_1_count) AS pos_1, Imagino que tengo que usar una variable o un array, pero no sé si se pueden embeber dentro de sql.
Lo cierto es que no he conseguido avanzar hacía la solución ni un poco. Me he metido en otras historias, que si crear conexión, sqli, pdo pero nada más.

Comment: Vale, he avanzado un poco (creo), pero me da un "fallo en la consulta", este es el código que estoy usando, https://pastebin.com/iZ94yBsz

Comment: Como te decía, ese código es obsoleto. Sugiero que pruebes primero usando mysqli como te indicaba antes: `$mysqli = new mysqli($host_name, $user_name, $pass_word, $database_name, $port);` directamente en el archivo y que hagas las consultas como explico en la respuesta. Si no te meterás en varias cosas al mismo tiempo y terminarás liado. Cuando eso funcione entonces te puedes poner a resolver las otras cosas. Las consultas mismas y hasta el diseño de las tablas podrían ser mejorables, pero es todo un mundo si lo abordamos todo al mismo tiempo.

Comment: Como te comenté esa conexión la hice, pero quería que funcionase sin meter los datos en el archivo, y acabo de fastidiarla pero bien exponiendo mis datos de conexión en pastebin y como no tenía cuenta no puedo borrar.
https://pastebin.com/8agAX6Ww

Comment: No veo que hayas puesto tus datos de conexión, o sea no hay riesgo en ese sentido. El que funcione en el mismo archivo o no es lo de menos. Haz  que funcione primero y luego separas la conexión colocándola en otro archivo. Eso no es tan prioritario, de lo contrario te vas a liar más con el problema.

Comment: En el link de pastebin que te he enviado es otro posterior, he omitido los datos de conexión tipo  $host_name = "my_host.com"; Pero antes había enviado otro aunque no puse aquí el link que si contenia datos, he cambiado mi password en cpanel. Como te dije hice la conexión, así que funcionar funciona y muestra la tabla provisional (la de la primera consulta). http://spark.byethost17.com/prem/?page=show_driversb