# ¿Como extraer una consulta de base de datos (MYSQL) a una pagina PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Quisiera saber de qué manera puedo extraer la información recogida en una variable de consulta php, para verla en mi documento html de consulta a la base de datos.

ANEXO: CODIGO PHP-HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<head>   <title>CRITICO</title>  
</head>  
<body>  
    <?php     
        $con=mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','','freatico') or die ('Error en la conexion');  
        $sql="SELECT * FROM medicion WHERE Nivel>=1.20";  
        $resultado=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die ('Error en el query database');  
    ?>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: es decir mostrarla como en una tabla?

Comment: Me refiero a extraer el resultado guardado en la variable de consulta "$resultado", para poderla ver en mi documento(pagina web).

Comment: Pues si tienes algun codigo que me sirva para hacerlo con estilos o tablas te lo agradeceria. Cualquier forma sive. El caso es que pueda extraer la informacion de la consulta.

Comment: [Aquí hay un ejemplo completo, en el apartado que dice **`Ejemplo con MySQLi`**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/93237/29967) donde se explica cómo construir una tabla a partir del conjunto de resultados de la consulta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Te pongo un código completo para que aprendas el control de tu código,
>   si solo quieres sacar los datos de la consulta, con el `WHILE` te
>   basta

```
<?php 
$con=mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','','freatico') or die ('Error en la conexion');  
    $sql="SELECT * FROM medicion WHERE Nivel>=1.20";  
    $resultado=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die ('Error en el query database');
//Valida que la consulta esté bien hecha
if( $resultado ){

  //Ahora valida que la consuta haya traido registros
  if( mysqli_num_rows( $resultado ) > 0){

    //Mientras mysqli_fetch_array traiga algo, lo agregamos a una variable temporal
    while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array( $resultado ) ){

      //Ahora $fila tiene la primera fila de la consulta, pongamos que tienes
      //un campo en tu DB llamado NOMBRE, así accederías
      echo $fila['NOMBRE'];
    }

  }

  //Recuerda liberar la memoria del resultado, 
  mysqli_free_result( $resultado );

  //Si ya no ocupas la conexión, cierrala
  mysqli_close( $con );

}


 ?>
```

Comment: Amigo. Hay un error en tu codigo.Me sale Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\freatico\critico.php on line 33

Comment: Eeeh... Bueno pues no se si tengas código de más, ese error por lo general es cuando tienes llaves mal cerradas.

Comment: Oye me funciono tu codigo. Pero el problema ahora es que yo quiero crear otra condicion, es que en el formulario la persona debe ingresar el numero de un punto para mirar su registro mas alto. Y entonces ahora ingrese un punto que no existia y me mando explicito lo que la variable consulta guardo.

Comment: Entonces, ese es otro tema, ya resolvimos el primero, deberás abrir otro para poner tu otra duda, recuerda marcar como correcta si te funcionó.

Answer (score 0):

### Lo solucionas de varias maneras pero te lo mostraré con un bucle WHILE

> Como te muestro en mi ejemplo las etiqueas HTML han sido agregadas y
>   ya con css les puedes aplicar el estilo que tu quieras

Como no muestras la estructura es decir las columnas de tu tabla, te anexo un ejemplo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<head>   <title>CRITICO</title>  
</head>  
<body>  
    <?php     
        $con=mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','password','blog') or die ('Error en la conexion');  
        $sql="SELECT * FROM posts";  
        $resultado=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die ('Error en el query database');  
        while($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc())
        {
            echo ("<p>".$fila["title"]."</p>");
            echo ("<p>".$fila["body"]."</p>");
        }

    ?>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Como puedes notar hago un while, ya que como bucle me ayuda a recorrer todo el dataset que estoy recibiendo de la consulta del servidor.

La variable `$fila` es la que almacena el resultado de dicha consulta, por lo tanto dentro de corchetes le voy a pasar el nombre de la clave o columna de mi tabla a la cual quiero acceder.

Uso fetch_assoc para poder tratar como array asociativo el dataset que estoy recibiendo

> Ahora al final para agregarle etiquetas **HTML**, solo las puse entre
>   comillas y las concatené o pegué a mi variable fila al inicio y al
>   final; en este caso usé una etiqueta p y con el signo de . se
>   concatena

### ACTUALIZACIÓN

Si lo quieres mostrar en una tabla solo guíate del ejemplo que dejo a continuación; los estilos te los dejo a tí para que los pongas

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<head>   <title>CRITICO</title>  
</head>  
<body>  
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>title</th>
            <th>body</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <?php     
            $con=mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','password','blog') or die ('Error en la conexion');  
            $sql="SELECT * FROM posts";  
            $resultado=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die ('Error en el query database');  
            while($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc())
            {
                echo ("<td>".$fila["title"]."</td>");
                echo ("<td>".$fila["body"]."</td>");
            }

            ?>  
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>  
</html>
```